# Python OOP only initialise object if function arguments are met

Tags: python, class, oop, initialization, arguments

How would I only allow an object to be created if the arguments are met? I tried using error handling but the object still gets created regardless of the value inputted.

```
class Age(object):
def __init__(self, age):
    try:
        if age > 5:
            self.testAge = age
        else:
            raise ValueError('Number is too low')
    except ValueError as exp:
        print(f"Error: {exp}")

def __str__(self):
    return f"Testing"

test = Age(3)
print(test)
```

In the example, I only want an object to be created if the Age is greater than 5. I use 3 as a test, the error is handled but the object is still created.

Comment: Because you caught the error in `except ValueError as exp:`. Remove the try/except block to propagate the error out of the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

When you raise the exception, you `except` it again

You can either remove the try/except or re-raise the Exception

```py
try:
    function_which_may_raise()
except Exception as ex:
    print("something went wrong")
    raise ex  # re-raise Exception
```